# How to use results of 3rd party api and append parameters in it

Tags: codeigniter

I want to convert today's date in to hijri date. For this i get codeigniter today's day, month and year separately.  For-example the url (Online api) is showing today's date in hijri. In which we are passing today's date, year and month.

```
https://hilalcommittee.org/api/hijridates/gethijridate?year=2020&month=2&day=20
```

and it is showing result as

```
{"hijridate":"28 Jumada al-Ukhra 1441"}
```

Now i want to use this url

```
https://hilalcommittee.org/api/hijridates/gethijridate?
```

and append parameters "year","month" and "day" and get hijri date dynamically. Please take a look at my code.

Controller class:

```
//show Hijri today's date
public function todayHijriDate()
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    $result = $this->hpm->todayHijriDate();
    echo json_encode($result);    
}
```

Model Class:

```
public function todayHijriDate(){
        $getTodatDate = new DateTime("now");
        $print_getTodatDat = $getTodatDate->format('d M Y '); // will print local date like 20 Feb 2020.
        $month = date('M');
        $year = date('Y');
        $monthDay = date('d');
        $path = "https://hilalcommittee.org/api/hijridates/gethijridate?year=$year&month=$month&day=$monthDay";
        return $path;

    }
```

Now problem is it is currently returning this result.

```
"https:\/\/hilalcommittee.org\/api\/hijridates\/gethijridate?year=2020&month=Feb&day=20"
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try to user http_buil_query to build the $path

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Can you please code it using my given parameters and url?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function todayHijriDate(){
        $getTodatDate = new DateTime("now");
        $print_getTodatDat = $getTodatDate->format('d M Y '); // will print local date like 20 Feb 2020.
        $month = date('M');
        $year = date('Y');
        $monthDay = date('d');

        $query = http_build_query([
          'month'=>$month,
          'year'=>$year,
          'day'=>$monthDay
        ]) . "\n"

        $path = "https://hilalcommittee.org/api/hijridates/gethijridate?".$query;
        return $path;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can try `return urlencode(path)`